# Second django instance running in another port is not loading in browser

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have setup the primary django instance at port 8000, and i've already been able to setup gunicorn, supervisor, and nginx. And it is running smoothly at domain - http://domain.com/.

When i try to run another django app via commandline using the following comand:

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:7772
```

The output gives me

```
0 errors found
Django version 1.4.22, using settings 'settings.sawan-local'
Development server is running at http://0.0.0.0:7772/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

When i try to access the app at http://domain.com:7772 - It doesn't load at all. No further logs are outputted in commandline (just the same as above). Any advice you might recommend I should look into?

Note: 
I am trying to run multiple copies of our django app in different ports so that i could test our feature branches separately. I have used different virtualenvironments, AND database for each app.

Comment: Yes. Firewall is not even running.

Comment: I thought it might be due to nginx, but i already tried stopping nginx. The app still doesn't load (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)

Comment: Are you browsing the application while connected to the server directly? If so, try `http://localhost:7772`

Comment: Yes i am running the server via commandline inside vps. :/ Accessing via localhost doesn't work.

Comment: Your port is being blocked somewhere - just try a different port. 7772 is the streaming port for quicktime (although that's UDP) but you never know.